# How to insert data from single column of a temp table into multiple columns of main table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a data like showed below in temp table:

```
col
-----
23041
ORF5674
FNRA
FIX_44
0
AE
```

Main table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_Act](
            [EventType]                 [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
            [ClientMsgID]               [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
            [SessionID]                 [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
            [Protocol]                  [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
            [MessageType]               [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
            [SequenceNumber]            [nvarchar](50) NULL,  )
```

I want to insert the data into main table.

Comment: Which row belongs to which column, are they in correct order ?

Comment: Have you got any other columns in the temp table that describe what sort of data each row contains? Is this the whole problem, or is it representative of something you need to do on a larger scale?

Comment: yes.. they are in order.   i have other rows too within single column (Temp table have a single column "col"), for which i have a logic to fetch. i want these top 6 records from temp column to be inserted into main table .

Comment: Do you have any other columns for the Order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[t_Act]
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN D.RN=1 THEN D.Col END)[EventType]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN D.RN=2 THEN D.Col END) [ClientMsgID]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN D.RN=3 THEN D.Col END) [SessionID]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN D.RN=4 THEN D.Col END) [Protocol]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN D.RN=5 THEN D.Col END) [MessageType]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN D.RN=6 THEN D.Col END) [SequenceNumber]
FROM(
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN 
    FROM #TempTable
    )D
```

If you have any columns to ORDER the row values, use that value in the above query.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderColumn)RN
```

instead of

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN
```

**This is not a 100% safe method.**

Comment: Thank you Dinesh.  It works fine , what might go wrong ?